# Как исправить ошибку Activity has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android, activity, android-service

Мне нужно что бы у всех активностей была связь с одним сервисом, я создал абстрактную активность от которой наследуются все остальные активности, и там я сделал привязку к сервису, что бы ее писать только в одном месте.
Но возникают вот такие ошибки, при переходах между активностями:

```
Activity PostActivity has leaked ServiceConnection AbstractActivity$1@416feef0 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity PostActivity has leaked ServiceConnection AbstractActivity$1@416feef0 that was originally bound here
```

Во кусок кода абстрактной активности где осуществляется привязка к сервису:

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected boolean mIsConnected = false;
    protected ServiceConnection mConnect;
    protected MyService mService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mConnect = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                mService = ((MyService.MyBinder)binder).getService();
                mIsConnected = true;
                onConnected();
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mIsConnected = false;
            }
        };
    }

    public void onConnected() {}

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mIsConnected) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnect, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        if (mIsConnected) {
            unbindService(mConnect);
            mIsConnected = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected abstract Fragment getFragment();
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: как минимум, вы биндите сервис в onResume, а анбиндите а onStop. Выберите либо пару onResume - onPause, либо onStart - onStop

Comment: Да я тоже сначала подумал что дело в этом, но поменял и все ровно вижу подобные ошибки, переключаясь по активностям, что еще можно сделать?